# ASP.Net WebApi do not return form data via Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I don't know if it's a bug but i'm unable to get raw request on server side.

Consider following controller method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/sayHello")]
[HttpPost]
public string SayHello([FromBody] string userName)
{
    return $"Hello, {userName}.";
}
```

I call it via cUrl:

```
curl -X POST 'https://localhost:809/api/sayHello' --insecure -d "=userName"
```

It works fine. 
[image]

Now I'm trying to add some logging. I add a global filter which is doing following:

```
public async Task LogFilterAction(HttpActionContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    LogFilterAction(context.ActionDescriptor?.ControllerDescriptor?.ControllerType,
        context.ActionDescriptor?.ActionName,
        context.Request?.RequestUri,
        await GetDataAsString(context.Request?.Content),
        context.Response?.StatusCode
    );
}

private static async Task<string> GetDataAsString(HttpContent content)
{
    if (content == null)
        return null;
    var contentBytes = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentBytes);
}
```

But here is the problem: for unknown reason reason contentBytes are always an empty array. I see that it's actual length is 9 (it's length of `=userName` string)

[image]

Or Even

[image]

As you can see, ASP.Net has successfully request arguments, however, it doesn't return it's in raw manner. Stream has position=0, contentConsumed=false, and everything else is just fine. But i ***can't*** read data passed to the controller.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API reads the content only once, so at the time that you access the content stream, it has already been read and the stream is positioned at its end. Another attempt to read the content will return nothing.

However, in a small sample I was able to reset the stream and read it again:

```
private async Task<string> GetDataAsString(HttpContent content)
{
    if (content == null)
        return null;
    using (var str = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        if (str.CanSeek)
            str.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var rdr = new StreamReader(str))
        {
            return rdr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

However, in order to avoid side effects, you might want to consider to use the [`ActionArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834140(v=vs.118).aspx) property of the `ActionContext`. You can use this property to retrieve the values that are handed to the action for logging. This does not interfere with the internal plumbing of ASP.NET Web API.